# ubuntu hardware somehow related to windows

Tags: sound, windows-7, 12.10

i just upgraded to ubuntu 12.10 and i noticed a very strange behavior. I restarted my windows and rebooted into ubuntu. My sound was not working in ubuntu, and i restarted again back to ubuntu. No luck. I then restarted to windows and restarted back to ubuntu and my sound was working.
I remember having the same issue with my wireless card back in ubuntu 9.04.

Any takes on this behavior so i can sleep better?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to switch-off the pc completely when switching from one sw to the other. I really don't know why, but seems that some resources (sometimes) remain locked.

Comment: noticed that my sound problem is back, after a while it stops working in ubuntu. gonna try your way though